# How to deploy a LOCAL docker image on a REMOTE docker host machine?

Tags: docker, migration

Assume that there are two docker host machines A and B and there is a docker image, xyz on machine A. I would like to deploy it to machine B from machine A. How can I do it?

I know that it is possible to operate on containers remotely by setting DOCKER_HOST as below, but this seems to require the docker image xyz already exists on machine B. Also, creating a tar file from the image xyz and coping it to machine B, and then running it on machine B is another way to do it. I wonder if there is a way in which I can do it directly from machine A? Thanks!

docker -H "ssh://my-user@machine-b" run -i - t xyz

Comment: The best approach would be to `docker push` the image to some registry, and then the remote machine can `docker pull` it.  Do *not* try to set up `$DOCKER_HOST`: it will not solve this problem, and it has some major security implications (if it's not configured _perfectly_ it gives an unauthenticated network path to unrestricted root access over the machine).

Comment: The `ssh://user@host` syntax of `$DOCKER_HOST` is as secure as the ssh connection. It doesn't have the issues people see with exposing the docker API to the network.

Comment: David, Thanks for your prompt reply. I am okay with ssh as I am doing tests for experiements, not for production. Your suggestion is good but I wonder if there is simpler approach.

Comment: BMitch, yes, using "ssh://user@host" is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As David mentions, the standard way to move images is with a registry. You can self host (e.g. [Docker's registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)), use a SaaS offering like Hub, or one of the cloud vendors (e.g. ECR, GCR). The advantage of a registry over sending exports is layers are deduplicated, saving you bandwidth when your image only has minor changes between versions. This functionality is also built into the docker engine with the push and pull commands.

With the save and load method, you could do this in two commads, piping the output, but as mentioned before this will transfer all the layers even if you only have minor changes:

```
docker save ${image} | docker -H ssh://${user}@${host} load
```

Comment: BMitch, I tried "docker save applications_xyz:us | gzip | DOCKER_HOST=ssh://bluestar@192.168.1.111 docker load" and it worked. I'd like to run it in a python subprocess and it does not work. This is what I have tried, subprocess.call(["docker", "save", "applications_xyz:us", "|", "gzip", "|", "DOCKER_HOST=ssh://bluestar@192.168.1.111", "docker", "load"]) and this is the error message I got, "cowardly refusing to save to a terminal. Use the -o flag or redirect." Do you see something wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: @D.Wang the `|` is shell syntax to join two commands, and that python call is most likely executing the command directly without a shell. Might work to call `["/bin/sh", "-c", "docker save... | docker load"]`

Answer (score 0):

I use Portainer Agent for this. Setup Portainer locally on Machine A on either port 9000 or 9443. Then add the Machine B environment using Portainer Agent on port 8000. Open the Machine B enviornment. You'll then be able to create containers, pull images, deploy stacks, whatever you need from Machine A->Machine B. It's a great way to migrate containers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BMitch, you can run your own registry. (See details in the documentation link above ⬆️)

Here is the commands to do so on Linux. It's a basic example for development use-case:

- a **laptop** (IP 192.168.0.22) where you code (will host the registry)
- and a **vm** (IP 192.168.0.55) where you'll publish and run the docker container.

⚠️ running a docker registry that way is **insecure**, please read the doc.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with docker version 24.0.6

---

On your developer's **laptop**

1. create a persistent storage:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/my_docker_registry
```

2. start a registry container: (here listening on port **5050**)

```
docker run -d -p 5050:5000 \
 --restart=always \
 -v /var/lib/my_docker_registry:/var/lib/registry \
 --name registry \
 registry:2
```

3. tag an image and push it into the registry (localhost is ok to reach it from the laptop)

```
# grab a container or build your own
docker pull busybox

# tag it and push the image into the local registry
docker tag busybox:latest localhost:5050/mybusybox
docker push localhost:5050/mybusybox
```

---

On the **vm**

You have to know the local IP of the laptop (supposing they share an common network). On local DHCP the IP may suffice and the lease may be always the same. Local DNS entry will be  very nice too. (left as an exercise for the reader)

We are configuring the vm docker client to allow to pull from our local remote insecure registry:

The following will create or overwrite the Linux docker config file: (backup it or edit it if needed)

```
echo '{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.0.22:5050"] }' \
  | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

reload docker's engine of the vm:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

test the docker pull from the vm

```
docker pull 192.168.0.22:5050/mybusybox
```

Should be happy to download the image from the registry.

---

All together with the initial question:

on the laptop side:

Let's have a local container from our own

```
# just to be sure...
unset DOCKER_HOST
docker build -t my-super-container .
docker tag my-super-container:latest localhost:5050/my-super-container
docker push localhost:5050/my-super-container
```

deploy on the vm from the laptop

```
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://remote_user@192.168.0.55
docker pull 192.168.0.22:5050/my-super-container
```

⚠️ if `$DOCKER_HOST` is set, all docker command executed in the laptop terminal session, will be executed on the vm now.
Including `docker build` which would build the container in the vm and not any more on the local docker engine on the laptop.

Of course the registry could be hosted on the vm instead, or any other third remote location.

Have fun with remote debugging!